# Using get() with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel 5 app that I'm trying to get data from two different tables: Endpoint table and Audits table. They are referencing each other by Endpoints.id and Audits.endpoint_id. I'm trying to get the audits for that specific endpoint but keep running into errors like `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()`

Here are my files:

**OnDemandController.php**

```
public function index()
{

$endpoints = auth()->user()->endpoints->where('is_ondemand', true);

$endpoint = $endpoints->get();

$mobileAudits = $endpoint->audits()->where('strategy', 'mobile')->first();
$desktopAudits = $endpoint->audits()->where('strategy', 'desktop')->first();        

return view('ondemand.index', compact('endpoints', 'mobileAudits', 'desktopAudits'));

}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
  @forelse($endpoints as $endpoint)
  {{ $desktopAudits->id }} - {{ $mobileAudits->id }}
  @empty
  nope
  @endforelse
```

**Endpoint Model**

```
protected $guarded = [];

protected $requestedAudits = null;

public function audits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Audit::class);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `->endpoints` returns a collection, while `->endpoints()` returns the query builder. `$endpoints` may already have what you want, but if not, use `->endpoints()`

Comment: @aynber not quite sure I understand, can you provide an example please?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `get()`? `$endpoints` should already have what you need.

Comment: Is "is_ondemand" from User?
If yes, you could try
auth()->user()->where('is_ondemand', true)->endpoints()->get()

Comment: @JoaoGRRR is_ondemand is from endpoints

Comment: @aynber im trying to get all the audits for a specific endpoint https://i.imgur.com/wzBPHhf.jpg

Comment: @aynber were you able to see my screenshot?

Comment: Yes, but have you checked `$endpoints` before you attempt the `->get()`? `dd($endpoints);` or `Log::info($endpoints);`, it may already have what you want.